# how to use TimedRotatingFileHandler for file name in python logging.basicConfig?

Tags: python-3.6, python-logging

For the first time I am using the Python 'logging' module, and currently, am trying to generate some sample log file with "logging.basicConfig()". My main motive is to generate sample log file with date in its name, "dd-mm-YY_.log". After doing some initial research, I found that we can use "TimedRotatingFileHandler" to accomplish the job. Below is the sample code from one the Stackoverflow post

```
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler
fh = TimedRotatingFileHandler('mylogfile',  when='midnight')
fh.suffix = '%Y_%m_%d.log'
```

But I am not able to make out on how would I go about using "format", and "level" from "logging.basicConfig" in TimedRotatingFileHandler() function.

Below is the whole python code that I wrote:

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler
log = logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(message)s', filename='log.txt', level=logging.INFO)
try:
    var = TimedRotatingFileHandler(log, when='midnight')
    var.suffix = '%y_%m_$d.log'
except Exception as e:
    print("expected str")
    logging.exception(e)

print(" ")
print("This is a Logging demo")
print(" ")
logging.info("new request came")
print(" ")
try:
    x = int(input("Enter the first number: "))
    y = int(input("Enter the second number: "))
    print(x / y)
except ZeroDivisionError as msg:
    print("cannot divide with zero")
    logging.exception(msg)
    print(" ")
except ValueError as msg:
    print("enter only integer value")
    logging.exception(msg)
    print(" ")
logging.info("executed successfully")
```

In the above code everything was working properly until I wished to introduce "TimedRotatingFileHandler" in the program.

Below is the error that I am receiving in my log.txt

```
2019-03-25 14:14:00,528:ERROR:expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/amitesh/PycharmProjects/Automation/Databases/DB_Conn.py", line 17, in <module>
    var = TimedRotatingFileHandler(log, when='midnight')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/logging/handlers.py", line 202, in __init__
    BaseRotatingHandler.__init__(self, filename, 'a', encoding, delay)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/logging/handlers.py", line 57, in __init__
    logging.FileHandler.__init__(self, filename, mode, encoding, delay)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1019, in __init__
    filename = os.fspath(filename)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
2019-03-25 14:14:00,530:INFO:new request came
```

From the above error it is pretty clear that I am not able to put the logic properly in the place.

## New Logs Structure

```
executed successfully
new request came
executed successfully
new request came
invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/amitesh/PycharmProjects/Automation/Databases/DB_Conn.py", line 61, in <module>
    y = int(input("Enter the second number: "))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
executed successfully
new request came
new request came
division by zero
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/amitesh/PycharmProjects/Automation/Databases/DB_Conn.py", line 62, in <module>
    print(x / y)
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
executed successfully
new request came
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'er'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/amitesh/PycharmProjects/Automation/Databases/DB_Conn.py", line 61, in <module>
    y = int(input("Enter the second number: "))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'er'
executed successfully
new request came
executed successfully
new request came
```

Kindly suggest.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This will do the job, you can customize the format too.

```
root_logger = logging.getLogger()
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s : %(msecs)d %(name)s %(levelname)s %(lineno)d %(message)s')
handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(FILE_PATH_OR_NAME, 'midnight', 10)
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
root_logger.addHandler(handler)
root_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the answer, and below is the modified code:

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler
LOGGING_MSG_FORMAT = '%(name)-14s > [%(levelname)s] [%(asctime)s] : %(message)s'
LOGGING_DATE_FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format=LOGGING_MSG_FORMAT, datefmt=LOGGING_DATE_FORMAT)
root_logger = logging.getLogger('')
logger = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler('amitesh.log', 'midnight', 1)
root_logger.addHandler(logger)
while True:
    print(" ")
    print("This is a Logging demo")
    print(" ")
    logging.info("new request came")
    print(" ")
    try:
        x = int(input("Enter the first number: "))
        y = int(input("Enter the second number: "))
        print(x / y)
    except ZeroDivisionError as msg:
        print("cannot divide with zero")
        logging.exception(msg)
        print(" ")
    except ValueError as msg:
        print("enter only integer value")
        logging.exception(msg)
        print(" ")
    logging.info("executed successfully")
```

Comment: But In the log file that is generated, I cannot find the date/timestamp, neither do I find the logger name, nor do I find the "level" as well. I have added the new logs generated in the original post. Surprisingly, I could see the logger name, level type, and date/timestamp in the console of my IDE. Not sure why its happening